# Can you explain this to me?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, definition

In Stefan Czerwik's *"Functional Equations and Inequalities in Several Variables"* there are a few lines I don't understand:

> Let X be a real linear space and A be a subset of X.
>
> A point a
>   ∈
>   A is said to be algebraically interior to A iff for every x ∈ X there exists an ε > 0 such that:
>
> λx + a ∈ A for all λ ∈ (-ε,ε).

Can someone explain how this definition is arrived at?

I also don't get the role of ε. Can you make it clear to me?

Comment: i.e. you can draw a 'circle' around the point and remain in A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simply means that $a$ is an interior point of $A$ if, when you move in any direction (the direction is given by $x$) starting from $a$, it will take a certain time (given by $\varepsilon$) until you leave $A$.

For instance, $(1,0)$ is not an interior point of $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x^2+y^2\leqslant 1\}$, because if you take, say, $x=(1,1)$, then there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(1,0)+\varepsilon(1,1)\in A$.

Comment: So does it mean (1,0) is at like the boundary and taking a small step in the y direction makes you go out of the set?

Comment: It's exactly that!

Comment: Thank you Mr Santos!

Answer (score 1):

The statement is saying that your element is interior if when you move a small distance away from that element (in the direction of $x$), you are still in the set.

It doesn't actually matter what $\epsilon$ is, it is just a sufficiently small number which will vary depending on what's been "picked" as $x \in X$.

Comment: Thank you Robinson! I have a doubt though, if a point is at the very boundary, is it still in the interior?

Comment: If it's right on the boundary, and there are elements in $X$ in the direction away then no, it is not interior. I believe that you *could* have a boundary element which is interior, for example in the if $X = [0, 10]$, and $A = [0, 5]$, then 0 is still interior as the elements of $X$ will still point into the set.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. The main thing to remember with maths like this is that $\epsilon$ doesn't actually matter, it's just the diameter of a circle you draw around a point. The basic reasoning is used a lot in Real Analysis.